# 3 Elements of Sℕ that are finite sets? (Natural Numbers)

Tags: natural-numbers

So i have

```
Sℕ = P(ℕ)
```

*1. I need 3 elements of Sℕ that are finite sets.*
My idea:

```
Sℕ = {x | x < 4)
```

does that work?

*2. I need to write down an element of Sℕ that is an infinite set.*

Well,  ℕ itself is already infinite  ℕ=`(1, 2,3,4,5......n)`

So my answer would be:

```
Sℕ = {x | x €  ℕ}
```

Correct? If not, would you like to correct me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does $S\mathbb N$ mean?

Comment: Sℕ = P(ℕ) so S contains all power sets of  ℕ.

Comment: Not following.  Why introduce a new notation for the power set?  Are you just asking for three finite subsets of the natural numbers?

Comment: I am going to ignore the fact that I ever saw $S\Bbb N$... and will replace every occurrence of $S\Bbb N$ with $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$ in my mind and response... I'm with lulu on this.  It should never have been written that way.  That said, if you are looking for three elements of $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$ which are finite sets, then *one* of the elements could be $\{x\in\Bbb N\mid x<4\}$ which is otherwise more simply written as $\{1,2,3\}$.  You still need two more elements... so how about $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  You only wrote one so far and it sounds like you thought this was three.

Comment: Next, you wrote "ℕ=`(1, 2,3,4,5......n)`"  No... $\Bbb N = \{1,2,3,4,5\dots\}$.  You wrote it with an $n$ at the end which makes it sound as though you think it stops at some point at some number $n$.  The set $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ is the $n$-element set $\{x\in\Bbb N\mid 1\leq x\leq n\}$ otherwise written as $[n]$.  As for an infinite element of $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$, yes $\Bbb N$ is indeed an infinite element of $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$.  So too is the set of prime numbers $\{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,\dots\}$ and the set of even numbers $\{2,4,6,8,10,12,14,\dots\}$ and many many many more.

Comment: Finally... please learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so you can correctly type things like $x\in\Bbb N$ rather than `x €  ℕ`.  There is no excuse for using the symbol for a Euro rather than the $\in$ symbol.

Comment: thanks! However, P(ℕ) can't exist inside a power set. So i assume my solution simply saying P(ℕ) = {x | x ∈ ℕ} can't be quite right?

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  What do you mean by $P(\mathbb N)$?  I assumed you meant the power set of the natural numbers.  That is, the set of subsets of the natural numbers.  But you say that "$P(\mathbb N)$ can't exist inside a power set" which is hard to interpret.

Comment: Oh, certainly, you are using equal signs in places you absolutely shouldn't.  **An element of** $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$ which is infinite is $\Bbb N$ itself.  This is not the same as the statement that $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$ is *equal* to $\Bbb N$ which is clearly wrong.  You should have written instead as $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)\ni \{x\mid x\in\Bbb N\}$ using $\ni$ instead of $=$.  As for "*$\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$ can't exist inside a power set*"  No, it absolutely can and exists as an element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N))$ for instance, the powerset *of the powerset of $\Bbb N$*.